# Python implementation of MFCC algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, mfcc

I have a database which contains a videos streaming. I want to calculate the LBP features from images and MFCC audio and for every frame in the video I have some annotation. The annotation is inlined with the video frames and the time of the video. Thus, I want to map the time that i have from the annotation to the result of the mfcc. I know that the sample_rate = 44100

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
from python_speech_features import logfbank
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

audio_file = "sample.wav"
(rate,sig) = wav.read(audio_file)
mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)
print len(sig)        # 2130912
print len(mfcc_feat)  # 4831
```

Firstly, why the result of the length of the mfcc is 4831 and how to map that in the annotation that i have in seconds? The total duration of the video is 48second. And the annotation of the video is 0 everywhere except the 19-29sec windows where is is 1. How can i locate the samples within the window (19-29) from the results of the mfcc?

Comment: Just a comment: Librosa has various feature extraction methods. It may help your work. https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/master/examples/LibROSA%20demo.ipynb

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
 mfcc_feat.shape
```

You should get (4831,13) . 13 is your MFCC length (default `numcep` is 13). 4831 is the windows. Default `winstep` is 10 msec, and this matches your *sound* file duration. To get to the windows corresponding to 19-29 sec, just slice

```
mfcc_feat[1900:2900,:]
```

Remember, that you can not listen to the MFCC. It just represents the slice of audio of 0.025 sec (default value of `winlen` parameter).

If you want to get to the audio itself, it is

```
sig[time_beg_in_sec*rate:time_end_in_sec*rate]
```

Comment: But there isnt also some overlap? This is what confused me.

Comment: I want to take the features of the signal and to use them for some further analysis. What do you mean to listen the MFCC (its coefficients of the frequency domain - how can i listen to them)?

Comment: re: overlap :  Of course. MFCCs are calculated over  `winlen`, and each `winstep`. So number of windows depends on `winstep`. Quality of features depend on 'winlen'. For different applications you use different windows sizes.

Comment: re: listening. I am glad you understand that.

Comment: Is it easy to calculate the jitter and pitch for the same windows, in order to enrich my MFCC features? Is it straight forward to do so?

Comment: You can do it. Pitch is not so trivial or reliable. You can't calculate pitch for the *same* windows (you need about half a second), but you can calculate pitch over whole signal and take value corresponding to the specific time window.

Comment: Any recommended python code for jitter and pitch? I want to check if they are useful for classification.

Comment: Also you mean mfcc_feat.shape not sig.shape, right?

Comment: ALso is it possible that i am receiving results in both channels? During the debugging i have checked that the MFCC has size indeed 4831 however there are two vectors inside it one its of size 13 and one of siez 26. Is there a chance that it is represantation of the two channels?

Comment: I can't answer that. It depends on `python_speech_features` implementation. It might be energies of the filter banks, but this you should check. re code, I did not use any Python implementations, sorry. You might search for Yin pitch detector.